# Python Regex Match Object Attribute Bug?

Tags: python, regex, attributes

I think I may have found a bug in py regex, or have I made an error?

```
import regex

...

iters = regex.finditer("Teams? [^u]*? rejected",file)
for Result in iters:
    Beginning = Result.span()[0]
    End = Result.span()[1]
    Text = Result.match()
```

Running the above code gives the following result/error.  It clearly outputs the regex.Match object with the match attribute then gives an error that the object has no attribute match.

```
<regex.Match object; span=(7684, 7708), match='Teams 1, 2 and 7 are rejected'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "b.py", line 72, in <module>
Text = Result.match()
AttributeError: '_regex.Match' object has no attribute 'match'
```

I wrote this code awhile ago on a different computer and it worked.  Now on my new computer it gives this error.  Not sure what my previous version of regex was, this is my current version.

```
>>pip show regex
Name: regex
Version: 2017.2.8
Summary: Alternative regular expression module, to replace re.
Home-page: https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex
Author: Matthew Barnett
Author-email: regex@mrabarnett.plus.com
License: Python Software Foundation License
```

Comment: 99.9% of the time, if you're wondering if it's a bug in popular software or you made an error, it's the latter.

Comment: I only say that because the code work fine on a previous version, now it doesn't.

Comment: The name of the standard Python regular expression module is `re`, not `regex`.

Comment: I know... I'm not using re.  That's why I included the import statement.  I need regex for fuzzy searching elsewhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`regex` is supposed to be compatible with `re`. There's no `match` property in the `Match` object returned by the `finditer` iterator. The way to get the match for the whole regexp is with `Result.group(0)` or simply `Result.group()`.

Also, `Result.span()[0]` and `Result.span()[1]` can be simplified to `Result.start()` and `Result.end()`.

See the documentation of [`re.Match`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#match-objects) objects here

I don't know why it worked before. Maybe an older version of the `regex` module was exposing an internal property, and this was fixed.